# jupyter print plot and dataframe in order, for loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to print the dataframe and plots in the order as in the code in my jupyter notebook:

- df
- plot
- df
- plot

Currently, they are printed as:

- df
- df
- plot
- plot

```
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(5), 'y': range(5)})

for i in range(2):
    display(df)
    display(df.plot())
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Force `plt.show` after you plot:

```
for i in range(2):
    display(df)
    df.plot()
    plt.show()
```